# SecurityContext authorities does not equal ServletRequest roles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security4

I was trying to replace some manual authority checking with annotations (`@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize`). While debugging why it doesn't work I was surprised to find that the second of these two assertions failed at the top of a `@RequestMapping` controller method.

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
assert(auth.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_READER"))); // passes
assert(request.isUserInRole("ROLE_READER")); // fails
```

I assume (as I can't get them to authorise anything) `@Secured` and `hasRole()` make use of the latter lookup?

Are the roles not supposed to be automatically populated from the `SecurityContext` authorities?

Was the filter that set the `Authentication` supposed to add the roles separately?

---

**Edit:**

Cut down the spring security config to spring boot's (1.3.0) default, plus the filter that sets the authentication.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your configuration... And which Spring security version you are using.

Comment: I am far from an MVCE - configuration is spread over many classes in many projects. This isn't a "find my bug" question, it's a "how does this work" question.

Comment: The only thing needed is the security configuration and an answer to the question which Spring Security version you are using.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you insist, but I don't see how that helps answer the questions of how spring web security works internally.

Comment: The Spring Security version is important as it might have or not have setup the servletrequest integration or not for this method. Also your spring security setup might break proper integration. Hence the request.

Comment: What does the `JwtAuthenticationFilter` do and what is the actual type of the `Authentication` you get returned? Also you shouldn't need `@EnableWebSecurity` as that is already done by Spring Boot and it might (and probably will) interfere with the auto configuration of Spring Boot.

Comment: It was my understanding that `@EnableWebSecurity` disables boot's config, otherwise I couldn't add my own filter.

Comment: The Authentication is a custom class, the filter creates an instance and calls `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication`

Comment: Your assumptions are also wrong btw, `hasRole` doesn't use the servlet stuff but the plain `Authentication` object. Do you have enabled method level security? Else `@Secured` doesn't do anything. Try `request.isUserInRole("READER")` instead.

Comment: Does `Authentication.getPrincipal()` return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume (as I can't get them to authorise anything) @Secured and hasRole() make use of the latter lookup?

My assumption was wrong. Both use the granted authorities, but in different ways.

- `@Secured` requires the prefix, so `@Secured("ROLE_READER")` works.
- `hasRole` does not use the prefix, so `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('READER')")` works.
- Both require the granted authority to be prefixed, so `@Secured("READER")` will never work, even if there is an authority named `READER`.

The prefix can be configured with `RoleVoter`'s `rolePrefix` property.

`HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole` uses a completely separate system, unrelated to Spring security. It is not populated by default, and does not need to be. I believe adding a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` to the chain will populate it

Comment: The assumption for your question was that you had setup proper integration for Spring Security with the servlet API (calling the `servletApi` to configure it).